# Basic tkz-graph usage problems, errors, bad output

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex, tkz-graph

I'm using TeXLive 2011 via MacTeX, and I keep my packages updated. I'm trying to start simple with `tkz-graph`.

When I use the following code, copied directly from the `tkz-graph` documentation:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \Vertices[Lpos=90,unit=2]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the error

```
Latex Error: ./myfile.tex:26 Package xkeyval Error: `unit' undefined in families `vertex'.
```

And when I try this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is:
[image]

Clearly something is very wrong, but what is it? How can I fix this?

---

**Edit:** Minimum breaking example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \Vertices[Lpos=90,unit=2]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And more information:

```
$ tlmgr show tkz-graph
package:     tkz-graph
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Draw graph-theory graphs.
longdesc:    The package is designed to create graph diagrams as simply as possible, using TikZ
installed:   Yes
revision:    22832
cat-version: 1.00
cat-date:    2011-06-24 10:33:31 +0200
cat-license: lppl
collection:  collection-pictures
```

And it's not my editor, either — if I run `latex` or `pdflatex` directly from the command line, the same thing happens.

---

**More edit:** in addition, it seems that even using `\SetGraphUnit` results in an `Undefined control sequence.` error.

Including `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tkz-graph.sty    18/11/2008 v 2.7d base for graphs
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Could you include the preamble of your file. This type of error is often of the type "problem with packages". In fact, you should include a complete MWE.

Comment: Sure, but the results are disappointing: I get the same behavior when I include nothing but `tkz-graph`.

Comment: I don't get any error from your example. Try adding `\listfiles` on top of the file and show what results in the log file (you'll find `*File List*` in it, and a longish list of the input files). I suspect an outdated version of PGF lying astray in some place.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the tip. I just updated the question to include the output of `\listfiles`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an old version of `tkz-graph.sty` in some directory searched by the TeX programs. You can find it by asking

```
kpsewhich tkz-graph.sty
```

which will return the file that's found first in the trees. Remove it: it is certainly outdated, as `\listfiles` tells, because the correct line should be

```
tkz-graph.sty    2011/06/01 ctan v 1.00 base for graphs
```

After having removed it, run

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

from the shell and you'll have a system in full shape.

Comment: Well sleuthed, sir!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include  `\usepackage{tkz-graph}` in the preamble, after which you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \Vertices[Lpos=90,unit=2]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use this exact input I get the same error I originally posted.

Comment: I suspect then you must be using older versions of the libraries. I am using the latest version of TeXLive2011 (updated last week). If I switch to TeXLive 2010 I get `LaTeX Error: File tkz-graph.sty not found.`

Comment: The output of `tlmgr show tkz-graph` includes `revision: 22832`, `cat-version: 1.00`,`cat-date: 2011-06-24 10:33:31 +0200`.

Comment: Hmmmm... Perhaps some of the other `tikz`related libraries are out of date.

Comment: Which would those be? TeX Live Utility doesn't show any new updates.

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Are you using TeXLive2011?

Comment: Yeah, via MacTeX 2011.